# find and count matches of a word on a website - scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need found the matches of a WORD, for example:

Found all words "Learn" in the web https://www.georgetown.edu/
(Result: 4 words) (you can see it press CTRL + F and search)

I have my Python code, but my count match is 3!
If I look for another word, the result is one less or one more

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = requests.get("https://www.georgetown.edu/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
solo_body = soup.body
limpiar_body = solo_body.text
contar_coincidencias = (limpiar_body.count("learn"))
print(contar_coincidencias)
```

Actually use Python3, "find_all" not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to count both upper and lower case.
replace `limpiar_body = solo_body.text` with `limpiar_body = solo_body.text.lower()`

Please note that it will give you `5` matches instead of `4`. The reason is it will also match the result from the top down menu, and there is one occurrence of `Learning` in the menu, as depicted below,

[image]

Comment: currently if I search for the word "learn" on the web the result is 4, but replacing the code the result is 5 (from which it takes that extra 1), but with my code the result is 3

Comment: I have explained why its giving 5 @BryanRivera, please re-read the answer.